# OpenVPN: hide server

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have installed OpenVPN on my server and I can connect it with my OpenVPN client.
Now I would like to hide the server from non-vpn connection.
I mean: you can see the server (and all services running on it) only if you are connected from vpn (and not from internet)

How can I do this? iptables + masquerading?

Could someone please help me with a good solution?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of help? You just block everything but OpenVPN on the IP interface connecting your server to the internet and allow everything from the respective `tun` interface.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example on how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: What you need is a good read of the documentation. Take this iptables tutorial here, it will get you where you need to be and provide you with some idea about what you are doing (which is really essential to have and what a simple example would not do): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Answer (score -3):

I think, easy way would be to block all ip's except the vpn's ip.
 Don't know how to technically say correct of course.